# Codeigniter: How to loop a result array in view page?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have to `forech` an array result, when I `print_r` the array, I got this result:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 35 ) [1] => stdClass
>   Object ( [reqcount] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 )
>   [3] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [4] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [6] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [7] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [9] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [10] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [12] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [13] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [15] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [16] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [18] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 2 ) [19] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [20] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [21] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [22] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [23] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [24] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [25] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [26] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [27] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [28] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [29] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [30] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [31] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [32] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [33] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [34] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 2 ) [35] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [36] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 2 ) [37] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [38] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [39] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [40] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [41] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [42] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [43] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [44] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [45] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 2 ) [46] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [47] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 2 ) [48] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [49] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [50] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 2 ) [51] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [52] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 2 ) [53] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [54] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [55] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [56] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [57] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [58] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 2 ) [59] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 2 ) [60] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [61] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [62] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [63] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [64] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [65] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [66] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [67] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [68] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [69] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [70] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [71] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [72] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [73] => stdClass Object (
>   [reqcount] => 1 ) [74] => stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 ) [75] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [reqcount] => 1 )

Please help me to `foreach` the result in view page

Comment: foreach ($yourArr as $value) {
    echo $value->reqcount;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your array is object type so use this code**

```
foreach($yourarrray as $value)
{
 echo $value->reqcount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting result in object form you can get values in foreach loop as:

**Example:**

```
foreach ($yourArr as $value) {
    echo $value->reqcount;
}
```

One more solution, if you want to convert object into array than you can just change the `typecast` by following this:

```
$array =  (array) $yourObjectArr;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not technically array, this array of objects, which means that when you foreach it, you need to access objects by pointer ->.

```
foreach ($array as $result) {
  echo $result->reqcount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have an Array with Object-Values in there.
To access your reqcount values, take a look on this iteration:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo $value->reqcount.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This should do what you want.